# output wav file multiple times larger in size than original

Tags: java, audio, wav

i am creating a copy of wav file but the output wav file is multiple times larger than the original file.(eg.for a file of 130 kB the copied file is 83.6 MB)
The size of data i extract from original wave file is itself very large.
Don't know what i am doing wrong.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         
    try {
long myChunkSize;
long mySubChunk1Size;
int myFormat;
long myChannels;
long mySampleRate;
 long myByteRate;
int myBlockAlign;
int myBitsPerSample;
long myDataSize;
byte[] myData;
long extensionbyte;
         byte[] tmpLong = new byte[4];
    byte[] tmpInt = new byte[2];
        DataInputStream inFile = new DataInputStream(new    
 FileInputStream("/home/therising/Rear_Center.wav"));                
         String chunkID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) 
 inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();
         inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the ChunkSize
        myChunkSize = bytesToLong(tmpLong);
        String format = ""+ (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) 
 inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();
        String subChunk1ID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) 
 inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();
        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the SubChunk1Size
        mySubChunk1Size = bytesToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the audio format.should be 1 for PCM
        myFormat = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the # of channels (1 or 2)
        myChannels = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the samplerate
        mySampleRate = bytesToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the byterate
        myByteRate =  bytesToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the blockalign
        myBlockAlign = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the bitspersample
        myBitsPerSample = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);
       inFile.readByte();

        // print what we've read so far
        System.out.println("format"+format+"chunkID"+chunkID+"SubChunk1ID:" 
 + subChunk1ID + " SubChunk1Size:" + mySubChunk1Size + " AudioFormat:" +
 myFormat + " Channels:" + myChannels + " SampleRate:" + mySampleRate);


        // read the data chunk header - reading this IS necessary, because  
not all wav files will have the data chunk here - for now, we're just 
assuming that the data chunk is here
        String dataChunkID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) 
inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();
System.out.println("  
myByteRate"+myByteRate+"myChunkSize"+myChunkSize+"myBlockAlign"+
myBlockAlign+"myBitsPerSample"+myBitsPerSample+"dc"+dataChunkID);
        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the size of the data
        myDataSize = bytesToLong(tmpLong);
        System.out.println(" ds"+myDataSize);


    // read the data chunk
   myData = new byte[(int) myDataSize];
   inFile.read(myData);

//System.out.println(" da"+myData.toString());
        // close the input stream

     DataOutputStream outFile = new DataOutputStream(new  
 FileOutputStream("/home/therising/my.wav" ));

        // write the wav file per the wav file format
        outFile.writeBytes("RIFF");                 // 00 - RIFF
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int) myChunkSize), 0, 4);   
 //04-howbigis the rest of this file?
        outFile.writeBytes("WAVE");                 // 08 - WAVE
        outFile.writeBytes("fmt ");                 // 12 - fmt
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int) mySubChunk1Size), 0, 4);     
// 16 - size of this chunk
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short) myFormat), 0, 2);        
// 20 - what is the audio format? 1 for PCM = Pulse Code Modulation
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short) myChannels), 0, 2);      
// 22 - mono or stereo? 1 or 2?  (or 5 or ???)
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int) mySampleRate), 0, 4);           
//24 - samples per second (numbers per second)
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int) myByteRate), 0, 4);           
// 28 - bytes per second
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short) myBlockAlign), 0, 2);    
// 32 - # of bytes in one sample, for all channels
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short) myBitsPerSample), 0, 2);  
// 34 - how many bits in a sample(number)?  usually 16 or 24
       // outFile.writeBytes(blank); 
        outFile.writeBytes("data");                 // 36 - data          
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int) myDataSize), 0, 4);      // 40 -        how big is this data chunk
      outFile.write(myData);
    inFile.close();
        }
    System.out.println("done");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}        

public byte[] shortToByteArray(short data) {
    return new byte[]{(byte) (data & 0xff), (byte) ((data >>> 8) & 0xff)};
}
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) 
{

int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    int shift = (i) * 8;
    value += (b[i] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
}
return value;



}

public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
return new byte[] {
    (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF),
    (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF),   
    (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF),   
    (byte) (a & 0xFF)
};
}
    public long bytesToLong(byte[] by)
{
  long value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++)
  {
  value = (value << 8) + (by[i] & 0xff);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: If all you're doing is "copying" the file, why not just copy it?  What other actions are you performing?

Comment: i want to embeed data in it and i have code for that but i wanted to focus on this size problem so i used simple copy process so that the unrelevant code won't take your time.

Comment: it's probably an endianess issue when you read myDataSize

Comment: samgak-where you think i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAV files are little-endian, but your `intToByteArray` and `bytesToLong` assume it is big-endian.

This will likely cause a problem such as you're seeing--because the sizes go through this conversion and the byte order is backwards. Small numbers will become larger and vice-versa.

So e.g.

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
    return new byte[] {
        (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF),
        (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF),   
        (byte) ((a >>  8) & 0xFF),   
        (byte) ((a      ) & 0xFF),
    };
}

public long bytesToLong(byte[] by)
{
    long value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++)
    {
        value |= ( by[i] & 0xFF ) << ( i * 8 );
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: but when i open the original file and copied file in text editor their chunk headers are same(for which i have used the same functions)

Comment: The chunk headers in the copied file will be the same because you are reversing the byte order when you read in and reversing it again when you write it out, without doing anything with the data, so the two errors cancel out. However, you are actually using the myDataSize variable to allocate your byte array, so that one matters and is the reason your file is the wrong size

Comment: What @samgak says is correct. Also, I've ran the code myself and verified this was the case.

Comment: thanks for investing so much ofyour time in helping.can you suggest some solution(modification in code)???

Comment: What do you mean? In my answer, I have the little-endian conversion. (Do you mean some other conversion?)

Comment: really sorry i didn't observed the edit and thought you are telling that these function need correction.foolish.sorry and thanks.checked answered.

Comment: It's no problem. ; ) Good luck.